# Kotlin equivalent of Scala Traversable.collect

Tags: scala, kotlin

Is there an equivalent in Kotlin for [Scala's Traversable.collect](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/Traversable.html#collect[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):Traversable[B]) function?

Specifically, I would like to map a List to a List, but only if that can succeed.

```
myList.map {
  val myNullableThing = it.someNullableMethod()
  // If it is null, then I cannot continue here
  // and I want to simply ignore this item
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although less generalized than the Scala `collect` function, `mapNotNull` should work in your case: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-not-null.html